# Android Studio installs 2 applications in my device after running the program

Tags: android, manifest

this program will install 2 application on my phone every time I run it. The first one named E-Waste Recycling and the second one named Main Activity. How can I remove the 2nd one? I just need the E-Waste Recycling

**This program manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.ccw.e_wasterecycling">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cenviro"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/cenviro"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Signup"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Users.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Admin.Admins"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCuN_T7G_WF_cA8SObet5eIrKZgZIzGaUw" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MessageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseIdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessaging"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me to solve that? your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is simply because you've got intent-filters with an action of `android.intent.action.MAIN`. This intent filter action should only be used on the activity that you wish to show launch first. You currently have two activities with this defined. If you remove one of these you should be good to go. But make sure it is in fact the correct activity that you wish to launch.

Comment: it does not install 2 applications. Your application has 2 launcher activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<intent-filter>` just for one activity!

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cenviro"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/cenviro"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Users.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Admin.Admins"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCuN_T7G_WF_cA8SObet5eIrKZgZIzGaUw" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MessageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseIdService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>

    <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: btw we can only use one  <intent-filter> in an application?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined launcher action multiple times. Remove intent-filter tag from MainActivity which will not show MainActivity after installation.

TL;DR:

Replace

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Users.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

With

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Users.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```